# Cyclic Namespaces in C#

Tags: c#

How truly "evil" are cyclic namespace dependencies within a single assembly. I understand using multiple assemblies changes everything and something like that wouldn't compile, but what is the real risk of doing it within a single assembly?

Answer (score 2):

No risk at all - feel free to reference anything you want within the same assembly.

However this approach will make you application brittle and hard to scale.  A better approach is to try and keep your components as orthogonal as possible.

What the language and compiler allow you to do is not necessarily what is best for long-term developments needs (bug fixes, scaling, new features, etc.).  You ought to strive for [loose coupling and high cohesion](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CouplingAndCohesion).

Comment: Understood, but I am only talking about a few instances where using something like separated interface is just not warranted and would be overkill.

Comment: Then in that case I don't believe you have anything to be concerned about :)

Answer (score 1):

namespaces are a way to provide a logical organization to your code. They provide a way to reuse names by applying it within a certain context. There is nothing wrong with having classes in two namespaces depend on each other.

Cyclic depedancies in assemblies is a bit more complex. Last I checked visual studio wouldn't allow this type of relationship directly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are any risks per se, and in some cases it's certainly the natural way of doing things. `System.Text.StringBuilder` obviously uses `System.String`, and I'd be very surprised if *nothing* in the `System` namespace used `StringBuilder` in turn.

It's probably worth just checking your design every so often: question whether you *should* be able to separate the functionality into separate components. Quite often the answer will be "no", at which point just move on with no feeling of guilt :)